# Merging 2 files with based on field match

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I want to create a file that contains columns from two input files. File1 is like:

```
aa 32
bb 15
cc 78
```

File2 is:

```
fa 19
bc 23
cc 50
de 28
aa 45
bb 31
```

The task is, read through File1, if the 1st field of a row exists among the 1st field of File2, then print that line of File2, with both columns and add the 2nd column entry of File1 containing the 1st field.

The output should be like:

```
aa 45 32
bb 31 15
cc 50 78
```

awk is preferred for the script.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a) {print $1,a[$1],$2}' file2 file1
aa 45 32
bb 31 15
cc 50 78
```

*Explanation:*

`awk` implicitly loops through each file, one line at a time.  Since we gave it `file2` as the first argument, it is read first.  `file1` is read second.

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  `NR` is the number of lines that `awk` has read so far and `FNR` is the number of lines that `awk` has read so far from the current file.  Thus, if `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first named file: `file2`.  For every line in `file2`, we assign `a[$1]=$2`.

  Here, `a` is an *associative array* and `a[$1]=$2` means saving file2's second column, denoted `$2`, as a value in array `a` using file2's first column, `$1`, as the key.

  `next` tells `awk` to skip the rest of the commands and start over with the next line.
- `($1 in a) {print $1,a[$1],$2}`

  If we get here, that means that we are reading the second file: `file1`.  If we saw the first field of the line in `file2`, as determined by the contents of array `a`, then we print out a line with the values of field 2 from both files.

Answer (score 3):

I like the awk solution but I think this might be easier:

```
sort file1 > sortedFile1
sort file2 > sortedFile2
join -o 1.1 2.2 1.2 sortedFile1 sortedFile2
```

The option `-o` will override the format which you will select to be first field of first file, second field of second file and second field of first file.

Comment: You can directly do `join ... <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Answer (score 0):

Join 2nd file, `File2` to the 1st file, `File1`.

```
join <(sort -k1 file2) <(sort -k1 file1)
```